# Getting incorrect text when extracting text from image using Python (Dot Matrix OCR)

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I am trying to extracting the text from image using the OpenCV via python but getting the incorrect result and mostly getting special characters,please correct what's wrong here

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os

def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Write image after removed noise
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.png"))

    return result

print('--- Start recognize text from image ---')
print(get_string("image_full_path.png"))
```

Tried Googling but none of things helped. can some one point to right code
output:

```
i } i er Oe a Pee pe be a

i j rye Se) PEE eet et ae ec?

j } a « o cy ” a @

: i : } Cand RET RE Petr eet PI ret

nif wad

fs | : : } wert
| ; a] |
wee | a
— th | cE i
ae | i
“ oe i j EYE }
en ct
. a f ae " i
- — ; - i! }
```

Comment: Please show the image.

Comment: Here is the image https://drive.google.com/file/d/133ViSHAnG6DWNoYuq8k_QB98l3V91ycB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The image is too bright and the contrast is not ideal.

You need to improve the [contrast and brightness](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html).

After that apply some [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) to remove noise.

Then follow [this tips](https://usabilityetc.com/2009/01/improve-dot-matrix-ocr-performance-tutorial/) on how to improve dot matrix printer fonts for OCR:

- Find the Edges
- Threshold the Greyscale Image
- Blur the Black & White Image

Comment: Thank you for very much for your tips, let me try ang get back to you.